# Joining lists into a vector

Tags: r, list, vector

I want to create the following vector using a, b, c repeating each letter thrice:

```
BB<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
```

This is my code:

```
Alphabet<-c("a","b","c")
AA<-list()
for(i in 1:3){
  AA[[i]]<-rep(Alphabet[i],each=3)
}
BB<-do.call(rbind,AA)
```

But I am getting a dataframe:

```
    dput(BB)
structure(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L))
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use the `each` argument  `rep(Alphabet, each = 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Akrun mentioned we can use the same rep function
create a vector which consists of letters a,b,c

```
A <- c("A","B","C")
```

Apply rep function for the same vector, use each as sub function

```
AA <- rep(A,each=3)

print(AA)

[1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `c` function to concatenate, not the `rbind`. This will give you vector.

```
Alphabet<-c("a","b","c")
AA<-list()
for(i in 1:3){
  AA[[i]]<-rep(Alphabet[i],each=3)
}
BB<-do.call(c,AA)
```

Akrun comment is also true, if thats what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also concatenate the rep function like so:
`BB <- c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3), rep("c", 3))`

Comment: Thanks for response. +1 for the trick. Actually I had a long list containing names, and I wanted to create a vector repeating each one consecutively for a certain number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution but note this form or appending is not efficient for large input arrays

```
Alphabet <- c("a","b","c")
bb <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Alphabet)) {
  bb <- c(bb, rep(Alphabet[i], 3))
}
```

Comment: Please, do not encourage newbies to use for loops in R whenthere are vectorized functions available, e.g,  `rep(c("A","B","C"), each=3)` - Thank you.